# RegEx: Add characters after number

Tags: regex, replace

I want to add the characters ,' after a number:

Input example:

```
(1SomeText;.Hello
(2SomeOtherText;.Hello
(3SomeAnotherText;.Hello
```

Output should be:

```
(1,'SomeText;.Hello
(2,'SomeOtherText;.Hello
(3,'SomeAnotherText;.Hello
```

Comment: And what language are you using ? The regex would probably be \d+ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following regex for search:

```
^\((\d+)
```

and replace:

```
($1,'
```